# IE6 PNG Replace: How to make a nested <a> clickable?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, image-replacement

For the purposes of this question, consider this:

```
<div class="has_transparent_png">
    <a href="foo.html">
        <span>
            <img src="logo.jpg" />
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

**The Problem:** In IE6, the `<a>` is not clickable. Here's the PNG replace I'm using:

```
.has_transparent_png {
    background-image: url(images/transparentpng.png);
}

* html .has_transparent_png {
    behavior: expression((this.runtimeStyle.behavior="none")&&(this.pngSet?this.pngSet=true:(this.nodeName == "IMG" && this.src.toLowerCase().indexOf('.png')>-1?(this.runtimeStyle.backgroundImage = "none", this.runtimeStyle.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" + this.src + "', sizingMethod='image')", this.src = "images/spacer.gif"):(this.origBg = this.origBg? this.origBg :this.currentStyle.backgroundImage.toString().replace('url("', '').replace('")', ''), this.runtimeStyle.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" + this.origBg + "', sizingMethod='crop')", this.runtimeStyle.backgroundImage = "none")), this.pngSet=true));
}
```

How can I make the `<a>` clickable? I have no control over the HTML. Only the CSS. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though there is no way to do this strictly through CSS, which was the intended goal.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but it seems that your are setting up that DOM structure to fix a transparent image on IE6. You may simply run a js function on specific ids to fix the transparency on images using a script like this one: http://homepage.ntlworld.com/bobosola/pnghowto.htm

Do something like this at the bottom of your page:

DD_belatedPNG.fix('#imgThatNeedsFix');

Hope that helps.

Comment: I wish I could use this fix, but unfortunately am not permitted to add specialized JS in this environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do..

```
.has_transparent_png a { position:relative; zoom:1; }
```

This won't always work...

Another alternative would be to use a sibling div to fill up the entire parent div with the png and then have a sibling div to that which contains the anchor and has a higher stacking order.

Comment: No go, it seems. Thanks for your help.